# NP reductions; if $Q_1$ reduces to $Q_2$, what can we infer about $Q_2$ given what we know about $Q_1$?

Tags: np-complete

I am trying to grasp this concept of reductions, which has surfaced during my study of NP-completeness.

So, my textbook notes that "if $Q_1$ reduces to $Q_2$, then $Q_1$ is at least as easy as $Q_2$." First of all, this claim seems counterintuitive. If a problem can be "reduced" to a different problem, shouldn't that mean that the original problem was harder than the first?

My second question is, if you know some information about $Q_1$, what similar information can you conclude about $Q_2$? For example, if $Q_1$ can be solved in polynomial time, what can you say about $Q_2$? Vice versa?

Hopefully I explained my problem clearly enough! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$A$ reduces to $B$" means that there's a way to take an instance of $A$ and "easily" turn it into an instance of $B$, so that - if I solve that $B$-instance - I can "easily" turn the answer into a solution to the $A$ instance.

This means that if I had a way to solve $B$, I could "easily" turn it into a way to solve $A$; this is why, intuitively, $B$ is harder than $A$.

For a concrete example: say $A$ is the problem of determining whether a number is prime, and $B$ is the problem of factoring a number completely. Then I can reduce $A$ to $B$ as follows: take a number $n$, factor it completely, and then see if I got at least three factors.

If you try to reduce $B$ to $A$, though, you get stuck. Say you had a magic wand that could tell if a number was prime. How would you use this to factor $n$? Well, first you could tell that $n$ isn't prime - but what then? You still seem to need to search through a lot of numbers to find $n$'s factors (and indeed, it is conjectured that $B$ does *not* reduce to $A$!).

This should help you see why the problem being reduced is easier than the problem reduced to.

---

This means the answer to your second question is, "Basically nothing." The only information you can conclude is **negative**: if $A$ reduces to $B$ and $A$ is *not* solvable in polynomial time, then neither is $B$. Positive information transfer goes the *other* way, e.g. if $B$ is solvable in exponential time then so is $A$.